# How do I display invalid form Dijits inside closed TitlePanes?

Tags: dojo

I have a large Dijit-based form with many Dijits in collapsible TitlePanes.

When the form validates, any invalid items hidden inside closed TitlePanes (obviously) cannot be seen. So it appears as though the form is just dead and won't submit, though, unbeknownst to the user, there's actually an error hidden in a closed TitlePane which is preventing the form processing.

What's the solution here? Is there an easy way to simply open all TitlePanes containing Dijits that are in an error state?

Comment: How are you validating? form.validate()? or validating fields specifically by iterating through them?

Comment: I have an onSubmit event on the form, and I'm calling this.validate().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing (I'm not great with Javascript, so this might sucked, but it works -- suggestions for improvement are appreciated):

```
    function openTitlePanes(form) {

        // Iterate through the child widgets of the form
        dijit.registry.findWidgets(document.getElementById(form.id)).forEach(function(item) {

            // Is this a title pane?
            if (item.baseClass == 'dijitTitlePane') {

                // Iterate the children of this title pane
                dijit.registry.findWidgets(document.getElementById(item.id)).forEach(function(child) {

                    // Does this child have a validator, and -- if so -- is it valid?
                    if (!(typeof child.isValid === 'undefined') && !child.isValid()) {

                        // It's not valid, make sure the title pane is open
                        item.set('open', true);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If validation is done by following, it will work:-

```
function validateForm() {
  var myform = dijit.byId("myform");
  myform.connectChildren();
  var isValid = myform.validate();
  var errorFields = dojo.query(".dijitError");
  errorFields.forEach(fieldnode){
    var titlePane = getParentTitlePane(fieldnode);
    //write a method getParentTitlePane to find the pane to which this field belongs
    if(titlePane) {
      titlePane.set('open',true);
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}

function getParentTitlePane(fieldnode) {
  var titlePane;
  //dijitTitlePane is the class of TitlePane widget
  while(fieldnode && fieldnode.className!="dijitTitlePane") {
    fieldnode= fieldnode.parentNode;
  }
  if(fieldnode) {
     mynode = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(fieldnode);
  }
  return titlePane;
}
```

Lets say if the following is the HTML and we call the above validateForm on submit of form.

```
<form id="myform" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form" onSubmit="validateForm();">
 ......
</form>
```

Comment: But I don't want to validate only the fields in the open tab (TitlePane, in this case).  I want to validate all the fields in the form, but open the TitlePanes which have fields with errors so the user can see them.

Comment: i believe that on validation on form, will highlight invalid fields. so i have used **dojo.query(".dijitError")** to get all the invalid fields. Let me know if it does not work with TitlePane.

Comment: It does highlight them. But if they're contained in a closed TitlePane, they're hidden from view.

Comment: did you try the above solution i provided?

Comment: ok. i did a bottom-up approach. you have done a top-down approach. otherwise, it is similar :)